# Move a view up when the keyboard covers an input field but with leaving some space between them

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uikit, uikeyboard

## Description

I have a few UITextField which I want to scroll up, when one of them is covered by keyboard during edition. There are a tons of answers here on SO with many flavors: moving a view (by changing its frame), modifying a constraint, using UIScrollView and UITableView, or using UIScrollView and modifying contentInset.

I decided to use the last one. This one is also [described by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html),  and has a [Swift version on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28813720/1656515) as well as being [described on this blog](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios) including a [sample project on the GitHub](https://github.com/woelmer/UIScrollViewWithAutoLayout).

#### Partial code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillBeHidden:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    self.activeField = nil
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    self.activeField = textField
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let activeField = self.activeField, keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
        let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: keyboardSize.height, right: 0.0)
        self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
        self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
        var aRect = self.view.frame
        aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize.size.height
        if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin)) {
            self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(activeField.frame, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: NSNotification) {
    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
}
```

## Issue

I want just one simple modification - a little more space between the keyboard and an edited field. Because out of the box it looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

I modified `CGRect` in `scrollRectToVisible` call, but it changed nothing. What's more, even commenting out the line with `scrollRectToVisible` had no effect at all - everything worked exactly as before (including scrolling up the content). Checked on iOS 9.2

Replicating, if needed, is trivial - just download the working code using the GitHub link above and comment out the scrollRectToVisible line.

#### Tested workarounds

Workarounds I tried, but didn't like the final effect:

- Increasing `contentInset` - user could scroll up more then the contentSize
- Replacing `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` with `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`, add another `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` observer with just `scrollRectToVisible` inside - it works, but then there are two scroll up animations, which doesn't look good.

## Questions

- Why changing `contentInset` (without `scrollRectToVisible` call) scrolls content in the scrollView? I've not see in any docs information about such behavior
- And more important - what to do, to scroll it up a little more, to have some space between an edited text field and the keyboard?

What did I miss? Is there some easy way to fix it? Or maybe it's better to play with `scrollView.contentSize`, instead of `contentInset`?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found why `scrollRectToVisible` doesn't work in the scenario described above, however I found other solution which works. In the mentioned Apple article [Managing the Keyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html) at the very bottom there is a hint

> There are other ways you can scroll the edited area in a scroll view
>   above an obscuring keyboard. Instead of altering the bottom content
>   inset of the scroll view, you can extend the height of the content
>   view by the height of the keyboard and then scroll the edited text
>   object into view.

Solution below is based exactly on extending the height of the content view (`scrollView.contentSize`). It takes into account orientation change and scrolling back when keyboard is being hidden. Works as required - has some space between the active field and the keyboard, see the image below

[image: screenshot]

**Working code**

I've placed the full working code on the GitHub: [ScrollViewOnKeyboardShow](https://github.com/iMikolaj/ScrollViewOnKeyboardShow)

```
var animateContenetView = true
var originalContentOffset: CGPoint?
var isKeyboardVisible = false

let offset : CGFloat = 18

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for case let textField as UITextField in contentView.subviews {
        textField.delegate = self
    }

    let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillBeShown(_:)), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillBeHidden(_:)), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}


func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}


func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    self.activeField = nil
}


func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    self.activeField = textField
}


func keyboardWillBeShown(notification: NSNotification) {
    originalContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset

    if let activeField = self.activeField, keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
        var visibleRect = self.scrollView.bounds
        visibleRect.size.height -= keyboardSize.size.height

        //that's to avoid enlarging contentSize multiple times in case of many UITextFields,
        //when user changes an edited text field
        if isKeyboardVisible == false {
            scrollView.contentSize.height += keyboardSize.height
        }

        //scroll only if the keyboard would cover a bottom edge of an
        //active field (including the given offset)
        let activeFieldBottomY = activeField.frame.origin.y + activeField.frame.size.height + offset
        let activeFieldBottomPoint = CGPoint(x: activeField.frame.origin.x, y: activeFieldBottomY)
        if (!CGRectContainsPoint(visibleRect, activeFieldBottomPoint)) {
            var scrollToPointY = activeFieldBottomY - (self.scrollView.bounds.height - keyboardSize.size.height)
            scrollToPointY = min(scrollToPointY, scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height)

            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: scrollToPointY), animated: animateContenetView)
        }
    }

    isKeyboardVisible = true
}


func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: NSNotification) {
    scrollView.contentSize.height = contentView.frame.size.height
    if var contentOffset = originalContentOffset {
        contentOffset.y = min(contentOffset.y, scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height)
        scrollView.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated: animateContenetView)
    }

    isKeyboardVisible = false
}


override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition(nil) { (_) -> Void in
        self.scrollView.contentSize.height = self.contentView.frame.height
    }
}


deinit {
    let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    notificationCenter.removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    notificationCenter.removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}
```

Comment: This works great for textfields. Textviews are a different story after making the necessary changes.