# Creating a Scroll View Protocol in swift 2.2

Tags: uiscrollview, uitextfield, interface-builder, swift-protocols, swift2

I am currently developing an iOS application with login and sign up forms. To make sure that the keyboard does not cover any `UITextField`s I've implemented the following solution provided by [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html) and discussed in this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813339/move-a-view-up-only-when-the-keyboard-covers-an-input-field).

To briefly sum it up, this solution uses a `UIScrollView` in which the different UI elements are placed and `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` to move the elements up and down when the keyboard appears/disappears so that the `UITextField`s aren't hidden.

This works like a charm except for one thing: for all my `UIViewController`s I have to repeat the same code. To tackle my problem I have tried:

- to create a base `UIViewController`, providing an implementation for the different functions, that can be subclasses by the other `UIViewController`s;
- to use a protocol and a protocol extension to provide a default implementation for the different functions and make my `UIViewController`s conform to it.

Both solutions didn't solve my problem. For the first solution, I wasn't able to connect the `UIScrollView` of my base class through the Interface Builder although it was declared.

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
```

When trying to implement the second solution, the `UIViewController` implementing my protocol somehow did not recognise the declared methods and their implementations.

The protocol declaration:

```swift
protocol ScrollViewProtocol {
    var scrollView: UIScrollView! { get set }
    var activeTextField: UITextField? { get set }

    func addTapGestureRecognizer()
    func singleTapGestureCaptured()

    func registerForKeyboardNotifications()
    func deregisterForKeyboardNotifications()

    func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification)
    func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: NSNotification)

    func setActiveTextField(textField: UITextField)
    func unsetActiveTextField()
}
```

The protocol extension implements all functions expect for the `addTapGestureRecognizer()` as I would like to avoid using `@objc`:

```swift
extension ScrollViewProtocol where Self: UIViewController {
    // The implementation for the different functions 
    // as described in the provided links expect for the following method

    func registerFromKeyboardNotifications() {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil, queue: nil, usingBlock: { notification in
            self.keyboardWasShown(notification)
        })
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(UIKeyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil, queue: nil, usingBlock: { notification in
            self.keyboardWillBeHidden(notification)
        })
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a good solution to my problem, knowingly how could I avoid repeating the code related to moving the `UITextField`s up and down when the keyboard appears/disappears? Or does anyone know why my solutions did not work?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I'll post it in case someone once to do the same thing.

So, I ended up deleting the `UIScrollView` outlet in my base class and replacing it with a simple property that I set in my inheriting classes. The code for my base class look as follow:

```swift
import UIKit

class ScrollViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    // MARK: Properties

    var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    var activeTextField: UITextField?

    // MARK: View cycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(singleTapGestureCaptured))
        scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        registerForKeyboardNotifications()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications()
    }

    // MARK: Gesture recognizer

    func singleTapGestureCaptured(sender: AnyObject) {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }

    // MARK: Keyboard management

    func registerForKeyboardNotifications() {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWasShown), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillBeHidden), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications() {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification) {
        scrollView.scrollEnabled = true

        let info : NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
        let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue().size
        let contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize!.height, 0.0)

        scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
        scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

        var aRect : CGRect = self.view.frame
        aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize!.height
        if let activeFieldPresent = activeTextField {
            if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeFieldPresent.frame.origin)) {
                scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(activeFieldPresent.frame, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }

    func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: NSNotification) {
        let info : NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
        let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue().size
        let contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, -keyboardSize!.height, 0.0)

        scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
        scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

        view.endEditing(true)
        scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
    }

    // MARK: Text field management

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        activeTextField = textField
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        activeTextField = nil
    }
}
```

And here is the inheriting class code:

```swift
class ViewController: ScrollViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollViewOutlet: UIScrollView! {
        didSet {
            self.scrollView = self.scrollViewOutlet
        }
    }

    // Your view controller functions

}
```

I hope this will help!