# Move view using Scroll View to prevent keyboard from obscuring text field or text view

Tags: swift, keyboard, textview, scrollview, textfield

I am implementing an app where tapping a button will pop up a location entry screen which is implemented with **Modally presented Segue** and **Visual Effect with Blur** to make the entry window appear hovering above the main screen.

The pop up screen has a text field for location name and a multi line text view for remarks.

Problem is the multi line text view is partially obscured by the keyboard on smaller devices and in landscape view.

[Landscape View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PD103.jpg)

[Portrait View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0SpJ.jpg)

[Modal Segue View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42HID.png)

I tried to utiize the solution described here, which is supposed to utilize scroll view to shift the view when keyboard appears, but it doesn't seem to work for my project: [Move a view up only when the keyboard covers an input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813339/move-a-view-up-only-when-the-keyboard-covers-an-input-field)

This question doesn't answer my problem as my text field and view are inside another view to make it appear like a popup to the main screen: [Move a view up only when the keyboard covers an input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813339/move-a-view-up-only-when-the-keyboard-covers-an-input-field)

In order to implement the pop up view (in a modal segue) I placed the text field and view inside a **View** which is placed inside a **Scroll View** which is located inside the view of the **Visual Effects with Blur View**.

Another problem I'm experiencing is I impleneted the following code to dismiss keyboard when tapping outside the text field/view, but for some reason it doesn't seem to work

```
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
{
    self.view.endEditing(true)

}
```

Here is the code for the View Controller of the pop up view in Xcode 9.2
Archive of the project: [Xcode Project Archive](https://www.dropbox.com/s/43mae39snk7y7le/Test%20Modal%20Scroll%20View%20Entry%20Screen.zip?dl=0)

```
//
//  LocationEntryScrollViewController.swift
//

import UIKit

class LocationEntryScrollViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var ScrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var LocationEntryView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var LocationTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var RemarksTextView: UITextView!

    var activeTextField: UITextField?
    var activeTextView: UITextView?

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        registerForKeyboardNotifications()

        LocationEntryView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        LocationEntryView.layer.masksToBounds = true

        LocationTextField.delegate = self   // dismiss keyboard when tapped outside keyboard
        RemarksTextView.delegate = self   // dismiss keyboard when tapped outside keyboard
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        LocationTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        RemarksTextView.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    /**
     * Called when the user click on the view (outside the UITextField).
     */
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
    {
        self.view.endEditing(true)

    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func DoneButtonTapped(_ sender: Any)
    {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func CancelButtonTapped(_ sender: Any)
    {
    }

    @objc func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification)
    {
        //Need to calculate keyboard exact size due to Apple suggestions
        self.ScrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
        var info = notification.userInfo!
        let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size
        let contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize!.height, 0.0)

        self.ScrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
        self.ScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

        var aRect : CGRect = self.view.frame
        aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize!.height
        if let activeTextField = self.activeTextField
        {
            if (!aRect.contains(activeTextField.frame.origin))
            {
                self.ScrollView.scrollRectToVisible(activeTextField.frame, animated: true)
            }
        }

        if let activeTextView = self.activeTextView
        {
            if (!aRect.contains(activeTextView.frame.origin))
            {
                self.ScrollView.scrollRectToVisible(activeTextView.frame, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: NSNotification)
    {
        //Once keyboard disappears, restore original positions
        let info : NSDictionary = notification.userInfo! as NSDictionary
        let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size
        let contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, -keyboardSize!.height, 0.0)
        self.ScrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
        self.ScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        self.ScrollView.isScrollEnabled = false

    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
    {
        activeTextField = textField
    }


    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
    {
        activeTextField = nil
    }

    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView)
    {
        activeTextView = textView
    }

    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        activeTextView = nil
    }

    func registerForKeyboardNotifications()
    {
        //Adding notifies on keyboard appearing
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWasShown(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillBeHidden(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    func deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications()
    {
        //Removing notifies on keyboard appearing
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move a view up only when the keyboard covers an input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813339/move-a-view-up-only-when-the-keyboard-covers-an-input-field)

Comment: No , my case is more complicated as I have the text fields inside a small View which is inside the Scroll View, I tried that solution (as I explained in my questions) and it did not work!